# Tree Sort in C++ traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm working on a problem where we are given an array, are to sort it using a linked list based Tree Sort and then traverse the tree to reform the (now sorted) array, without using vectors.  Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

// sorts b[0..n-1] into non-descending (i.e. ascending) order.

struct tNode { int val; tNode * leftC; tNode * rightC; };

void insert(tNode * &here, int val) {
    //base case
    if (here == NULL) {
        here = new tNode();
        here->val = val;
        here->leftC = here->rightC = NULL;
        return;
    }
    else if (val <= here->val) {
        insert(here->leftC, val);
    }
    else {
        insert(here->rightC,val);
    }
}

int traverse(tNode * node) {
    if (node == NULL) return -1;
    if (!node->leftC == NULL)traverse(node->leftC);
    int r = node->val;
    if (!node->rightC == NULL)traverse(node->rightC);
    else {
        node = NULL;
        return r;
    }

}

void sortWithTree(int b[], int n) {
    tNode * root = NULL;
    tNode * p = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        insert(p, b[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = traverse(root);
    }
}
```

The Traverse is returning -1 every time.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That function returns -1 because either the node is NULL, `r` is `-1`, or the function failed to return a value (which yours does at the end), and the value that is returned by chance is `-1`.  Take your pick (debug your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in traverse.

I guess your intention is for the call to traverse to return the smallest number contained in the tree and to remove that value from the tree.
So that succesive calls return the members in increasing order.
But that is difficult to do with your structure since nodes contain middle values. Once a value is returned you would need to erase it but without erasing the right node.
Another problem is that the parameter node is not passed by reference (by reference to a pointer to be precise) thus the instruction `node = NULL;` has no effect in the tree.

Rather than fixing your traverse I'll instead go for an easier strategy. Fill the array in a single run of traverse. traverse will not return any element, instead it will receive a pointer to the array and store the elements there increasing the pointer as it goes.

```
void traverse(tNode * node, int*& p) {
    if (node == NULL) return;
    traverse(node->leftC, p);
    *p = node->val;
    ++p;
    traverse(node->rightC, p);
}

void sortWithTree(int b[], int n) {
    tNode * root = NULL;
    tNode * p = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        insert(p, b[i]);
    }
    int *bTmp = b;
    traverse(root, bTmp);
}
```

Both your code and mine still have something left to do. To `delete` all dynamic memory once we are done with the tree. If you understand how my traverse works you should be able to do it yourself.